# How to know when a JTable has been sorted

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I need to know when a JTable has been sorted, after the new row order is shown on the table.

I tried with:

```
 getModel().addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener() {        
        @Override
        public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
            System.out.println("change");               
        }
    });
```

But the method `tableChanged(TableModelEvent e)` seemed not to be called after sorting.

Comment: The model is never sorted, the view is sorted. A view maps to the model in the JTable by way of index mapping.

Comment: Also, just for clarity can you explain why you need to know when the table has been sorted?

Comment: I have to order a JTable filled from a Excel file. Since I can't find a way to order all the rows except the ones that are cell header, I thought that I may wait until the JTable is sorted, and then find  a way to remove cell headers from their position and put them at the top of the JTable.

Comment: The question is why are you loading the "header" values as part of the row data. The first row should be read separately to create the "column names"  for the table. The column names are displayed as a separate part of the JTable. Read the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for examples.

Comment: HI @camickr. Actually I don't how many row header  the excel will have. I've been asked to show, before the data rows, all the header rows in the excel file, even if the rows are empty. I have to replicate the exact presentation of the excel files.
Does JTable allow to have many "headers" rows?

Comment: *Does JTable allow to have many "headers" rows?* - no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorting and related events in a JTable are handled by a [RowSorter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/RowSorter.html). They can be set using [JTable.setRowSorter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setRowSorter(javax.swing.RowSorter)).

A RowSorter allows you to listen to sorting events, by subscribing a listener using [RowSorter.addRowSorterListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/RowSorter.html#addRowSorterListener(javax.swing.event.RowSorterListener)).

This listener is of interface [RowSorterListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/event/RowSorterListener.html), the listener method receives an instance of [RowSorterEvent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/event/RowSorterEvent.html). When the [Type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/event/RowSorterEvent.html#getType()) of this event is [Sorted](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/event/RowSorterEvent.Type.html), this indicates that:

> [...] the contents have been newly sorted or transformed in some way.

---

For your understanding: a traditional JTable (i.e. an implementation that follows the specification) will not sort the model. Instead, an array of indexes to the model is sorted instead. This is typical for UI elements that following the Model/View paradigm.

Comment: I already tried using addRowSorterListener().  The problem is that it is called before the new rows order is shown on the table. I need to know when the table is updatedfor this reason: I have to order a JTable filled from a Excel file. Since I can't find a way to order all the rows except the ones that are cell header (in excel), I thought that I may wait until the JTable is sorted, and then find a way to remove cell headers from their position and put them at the top of the JTable.

Comment: @MDP Make your own sorter, that sorts the headers before anything else in all cases. Better still, have the header values in the table header so you don't run into this problem at all. Headers, that's what the JTable header is for.

Comment: I can't use JTable header, since I have to respect the Excel file presentation. If in the file excel there is one empty row, then a row with headers, then another empty row before data, I have to have 3 "headers" rows before "data" rows :(. That's my problem.
I can try to follow your tip to create my empty row, but I don't know how to do, I've never worked on java application before :(

Comment: @MDP You could also create a JTable for each "table" you get from Excel, which would allow you to use the JTable header and not bother with the sorting shenanigans? Then add those JTable instances to a JPanel with a FlowLayout or BoxLayout, one after the other?

Comment: @MDP If you really cannot do this now, one "hack" of sorts would be to do what you need to do in a `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` that is launched from the rowsorter listener that I describe in my answer. That would put your "processing" in the EDT-queue and would be processed after all else (and hopefully after the sorting instead of before).

Comment: Thank you @TT, you are very kind and very patient. Probably ill try to add another JTable to show header. I already thought about this solution; since I'm not used to work with java applicaiton, I was just afraid to having problem when I have to handle the size of the columns of the "header" JTable when users resize the respective columns of the "data" JTable (and vice versa). I hope it is easy :)

Comment: @MDP Trying to force a JTable to behave like an Excel page will be extremely hard. Also, trying to force multiple JTable controls to behave like one Excel page, will also be extremely hard. Without delving too deep into it, if I really had to do this with a JTable control I'd do it with a specially crafted RowSorter, and have meta-information in the rows to know to what virtual table each row belongs to, plus meta-info for when a row is a header. Then do sorting based on table-id, is_header, and data rows. In any case: good luck :)